# Hector Mutator Execution Real Time Difference

Tags: cassandra, hector

We're using Hector API to process on Cassandra. However, there is something strange going on about the execution time.

```
long methodCallElapsed1 = System.nanoTime();
MutationResult mr = mutator.execute();
long methodCallElapsed2 = System.nanoTime();
long methodCallElapsed3 = mr.getExecutionTimeMicro();
```

We hope to find the difference between methodCallElapsed2 - methodCallElapsed1 slightly close to methodCallElapsed3, however methodCallElapsed2 - methodCallElapsed1 = 33 ms and methodCallElapsed3 = 1,8 ms?

Can anyone explain the difference?